# Audit selection is poor IMO

Tags: discussion, review-audits

i dont want to whine about a ban, but can someone check this audit?
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24422336

This answer is certainly not the perfect one but its not too stupid either. The person points out a specific firmware where the fix is applied for the authors question/problem.

My choice was "no action needed". I have seen so many worse answers on this site, that i think this is definitely not below average. Like i said, i will wait the 14 days or something but still i think thats this particular audit is not very useful. If i downvote this thing, i need to downvote every third answer i will get as a review.

Comment: I've cast an undelete vote on that. It might very well be the proper answer to that question (Is there support for multiple printers? Yes, since 2.12.0, but you're using 2.9.0). I don't think you've made the wrong call on that answer, however, 4 persons did vote to delete it from [VLQ review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24350888).

Comment: thanks for your support on that one. In the past i definitely agreed to a false audit by myself and learned from it, but here i really wouldnt decide otherwise next time. To me its useful for the authors question, even if its certainly not the premium gold standard answer :-)

Comment: Personally, I would say that 'answer' would be better as a comment. But, yes, it seems a bit too 'borderline' for an audit. I guess the (presumably automated) system for audit selection need some looking into.

Comment: Quite possibly the answer shouldn't have been deleted, but IMO "No action needed" definitely wasn't the right choice. It contains no references (where does Epson say that?), lacks capitalization, and has an unnecessary sentence *Please tell us if it works.*. I would have edited to improve it *and* commented asking for elaboration. (how, in 2.12.0, can one add multiple printers?)

Comment: If i audit for no action taken on  "thanks for any answers" issues or "please tell us if this works" then i could ban every reviewer on this site pretty fast. But like i said. I will live with it. Still have the same oppinion as two other commenters here.

Comment: If you are reviewing at all, particularly on queues like "first posts", is to look out for that kind of issues, not only for unredeemable posts.

Comment: @yivi ok... then my takeaway is that i will go full in and edit/delete any bullshit like those "thanks" and "please" and "hi guys" and formatting issues. Just up until now i though that this is a fight nobody of us can win. i started it once but then it was just too much of this phrases ... like in every 2nd post.

Comment: Certainly, we do not help by clicking on "No Action Needed" when we see that kind of thing on a user's first post.

Comment: but lets be honest. If every reviewer would do it this way, i wouldnt see thousands of posts on stackoverflow with exactly that phrases in it. I am not mainly a reviewer but am locked into programming topics.

Comment: *then my takeaway is that i will go full in and edit/delete any bullshit like those "thanks" and "please" and "hi guys" and formatting issues* Most definitely - edit to remove the unnecessary stuff whenever you see it, while reviewing (and outside of review too, if you wish). The whole point of review is to make it so that the visible posts others see are better presented and more useful, without noise.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok. Agreed. Will take action on that again.

Comment: marked the question as duplicate as offered by moderator. So this is it.

Comment: From what I am reading it is just a comment saying that the company said something is possible with a certain version but anyone viewing would have to go look it up themselves to verify. At the very least they could provide a link to where this information is.

Comment: Just to clarify: no moderators have been involved with *any* of this. That [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24350888) was initially flagged, reviewed, and then deleted by the community (no moderators involved). The audit was automatically chosen on that basis (not selected by a moderator). Finally, no moderators have interacted with *this* question, up until now. The duplicate you accepted was not proposed by a moderator. Moderators are indicated by a diamond next to their user name, like mine has.

Comment: That said, I agree with @CertainPerformance. The answer may be useful, and even correct, but it is of extremely poor quality. It needed to be edited, even if not deleted. As such, "no action needed" was the wrong choice. Editing is an action. You claim that, were that the case, every answer on the site would need editing. Well, that's not quite true, but it is certainly true that "no action needed" is almost *always* the wrong choice in the review queues. Good answers rarely end up in there. When in doubt, of course, you can always click "Skip".

Comment: Note finally that, thanks to your bringing it to the community's attention, [that answer has been undeleted, edited, and commented](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58458064/revisions). This removes it from the list of audit candidates, so no one will ever get this audit again.

Comment: Nice that my ban is useful.. at least for others not getting this very bad review question ;-)